# I want to stop print() from printing space while using ,

Tags: python

I am a noob so this question maybe a crap for you.

As written in title, I want to stop `print()` from printing space while using `,`.

I have code for that :

```
i = 1
print (i,"2")
```

> **Output** = 1 2
>
> **Expected Output** = 12

Comment: try this: `print (str(i)+"2")`

Comment: The simplest for your case is `print (i,"2",sep='')`

Comment: Make an effort. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) instead:

```py
i = 2
print(f"{i}2")
```

Comment: This will raise a SyntaxError. Maybe you mean: `print("{}2".format(i))`

Comment: @LaurinO This is a new feature called f-strings which was introduced in Python3.6, it runs fine: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

Comment: @kalehmann: You are right. I just tried it in a newer Python version. Thx, I did't know.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
i = 1
print(i,"2",sep='')
```

or by use of `str.format()`:

```
i = 1
print("{}2".format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good practise, but it certainly gets the job done:

```py
print(i+"2")
```

Also as a note you should have `i = "1"` as it should be a string.

Comment: This will raise `TypeError` if `i` is not `str`